# Lean method to creating hover and click functionality with to an SVG directory map with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've got an SVG directory map with about 30-40 listings. I've added classes to paths that make up each of the locations within.

Here's where it gets tricky,

The goal is to provide a tooltip hover effect for each of the listings with the business name and when you click it should take you to the corresponding page.

I could write the jQuery for each one but there has to be a better way than writing 30 different click rules and 30 more hovers.

Edit: Here is the current treatment:

```
$(".location-m1").hover(function(){
    $(".directory-m1").css("display", "block");
    $(".location-m1").css("opacity", ".7");
}, function(){
    $(".directory-m1").css("display", "none");
    $(".location-m1").css("opacity", "1");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HeliumVideo/sepzgakr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something is a lot more dynamic, and that gets the classname from the hovered element and uses it to access the other elements etc.

```
$(".location").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var klasses = this.getAttribute('class').trim().split(/\s+/);
    var klass = klasses.filter(function(klass) {
        return klass.indexOf('location-') === 0;
    }).shift().split('-').pop();

    var disp = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'block' :  'none';
    var opaq = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 0.7 : 1;

    $(".directory-" + klass).css("display", disp);
    $(".location-"  + klass).css("opacity", opaq);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bu7s4xc4/)